# Why does my code to update data attributes not work?

Tags: html, jquery, custom-data-attribute

I have the following code:

```
<div 
    class="continueReading" 
    data-skip="0" 
    data-categories="22,243" 
    data-is="single" 
    data-s="cd1f2f7a7d" 
    data-list="latestNews-sidebar-1"
>
    <a href="javascript:void();" class="latestNewsWidgetMoreLink">get more</a>
    <a href="javascript:void();" class="latestNewsWidgetMoreButton">»</a>
</div>
```

---

```
$('.latestNewsWidgetMoreLink, .latestNewsWidgetMoreButton').click(
    function()
    {    
        total_items = 10;
        $(this).parent('div').attr('data-skip', total_items);
    }
);
```

but seems don't work. Can somebody to help me? Is there any error in this code?

**Note**: I have also try the following code with no luck:

```
total_items = 10;
$(this).parent('div').data('skip', total_items);
```

Comment: As Adil said, show us the HTML. Also show us the function(s) surrounding those few lines - hard to work out if there's an issue if we don't know what `this` is in the context of the code.

Comment: How are you expecting to know if it's worked if you're setting the value of the data attribute to the same thing?

Comment: Even in this code doesn't work (note have change the value of the div data attribute)

Comment: Where's the script located in relation to the HTML document - in the `<head>` tag, somewhere in the `<body>` tag, just before the `</body>` tag? It may be executing before the elements exist, in which case you'd need a DOM ready handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code works for me in [this example jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MfYLk/). I suspect the code is executing too early, and as a result the `click` event handlers aren't being bound to the elements (because they don't exist yet). Try wrapping it in a `$(document).ready()` call:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.latestNewsWidgetMoreLink, .latestNewsWidgetMoreButton').click(function () {
        total_items = 10;
        $(this).parent('div').data('skip', total_items);
    });
});
```

That will ensure the code doesn't execute until the DOM is ready, so the elements will exist and can have event handlers bound.

Note that I've made a couple of adjustments:

1. Removed the semi-colons from the `href` attributes of the `<a>` elements - was causing a JavaScript syntax error
2. Using the `.data()` jQuery function rather than `.attr()`

Answer (score 1):

Remove `javascript:void();` from both link and then inspect HTML DIV with firebug and click on link , it will set `data-skip="10"`;

Answer (score 1):

The code works fine. See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/PBt7f/1/). The second link won't work because you have forgot the dot
in the jQuery selector. So you have to change

```
$('.latestNewsWidgetMoreLink, latestNewsWidgetMoreButton')
```

in

```
$('.latestNewsWidgetMoreLink, .latestNewsWidgetMoreButton')
```

Comment: Sorry @pbaris, but I had a mistake in my code above. In my real code, I have the (.) before the latestNewsWidgetMoreButton. Thanks a lot for your assistance :)